# How do I handle an apostrophe (') in MS SQL 2008 FTS?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, full-text-search

I have a website that utilizes MS SQL 2008's FTS (Full-Text Search). The search works fine if the user searches for a string with an apostrophe like **that's** - it returns any results that contain **that's**. However, it will not return a result if the user searches for **thats**, and the database stores **that's**.

Also, ideally a search for **that's** should also return **thats** and **that**, etc.

Anybody know if FTS supports this, and what I can do to enable it?

WT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a parameter

```
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@searchterm", txtSearch.Text.Trim());
```

it will be handle by you, without any hassle.

regarding that, that's and thats you should look up [SOUNDEX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259235%28SQL.80%29.aspx) keyword. [4GuysfromRolla](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020202742/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com) have an [old article](https://web.archive.org/web/20210325072131/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/tips/t103101-1.shtml) about it as well.

**updated**
there is a great talk from one of the TFS Team member regarding this [here](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/forumarchives/SQLServerfulltext/Jul2005/post23397705.asp).

quoting him:

> Daniel is correct Full-text Search (FTS) does not use SOUNDEX directly,
> but      it can be used in combination with SOUNDEX. 
> Additionally, you may
> want to      review the following links as well as the below TSQL
> examples of combining **CONTAINS** & **SOUNDEX**
> You may want to look at
> some of the improved soundex algorithms as well as the
> **Levenshtein Distance algorithm**
>  You
> should be able to search Google to find more code examples, for example:
> 'METAPHONE soundex "sql server" fuzzy name search' and I quickly found -
> "Double Metaphone Sounds Great" at http://www.winnetmag.com/Article/ArticleID/26094/26094.html
> You can freely download the code in a zip file that has several a user-defined function  (UDF) that implement Double Metaphone.      
> Below
> are some additional SOUNDEX links:
> http://www.merriampark.com/ld.htm
> http://www.bcs-mt.org.uk/nala_006.htm

*(omitted for out of scoop)*

```
use pubs     

-- Combined SOUNDEX OR CONTAINS query that 
-- Searches for names that sound like "Michael".      
SELECT 
    au_lname, au_fname 
FROM 
    authors -- returns 2 rows      
WHERE 
    contains(au_fname, 'Mich*') or SOUNDEX(au_fname) = 'M240'
```

> Thanks,
> John
> SQL Full Text Search Blog
> http://spaces.msn.com/members/jtkane/

Comment: Hi, thanks for the links. I didn't understand the part about parameters - I am using a SP which I am already passing values to. Is this what you meant?

Comment: Yes. You could be using inline SQL and were struggling about the single quote char, but using parameters like I show, all special chars will be passed correctly. - Added more content regarding SOUNDEX and FTS -

Comment: Ok, thanks - I was immediately able to solve the problem using DIFFERENCE, which is a variant of SOUNDEX! Brilliant! Thanks! Will also read the links you've sent, in case there's something I should be careful about...

Comment: SOUNDEX is an i18n disaster waiting to happen.

Comment: MSalters, that's fine - we're targeting only one language.